# Cannot click on a visible link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to click on a link which is located on an li list.  Whenever I use a locator to find this element I get nothing in return.  I've tried searching by element, the number id, chaining classes, etc. still coming up with nothing. I've noticed when I highlight the link with mouse the html changes and ads hovered to the code.
Here is the .html without hover:

```html
<li id="168283" class="jstree-leaf" rel="meetingSpace">

<ins class="jstree-icon">
    </ins>
<a class="" href="#" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <ins class="jstree-icon" style="background-color: transparent;">
        </ins>
  Salon A

</a>

</li>
```

the .html with hover:

```html
<li id="168283" class="jstree-leaf" rel="meetingSpace">

<ins class="jstree-icon">
    </ins>
<a class="jstree-hovered" href="#" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <ins class="jstree-icon" style="background-color: transparent;">
        </ins>
  Salon A

</a>

</li>
```

I have to be honest I'm not great with .html but I'm learning, however this has thrown me for a loop

Some code I've tried:

```js
element(by.xpath("//li[@id='168283']/a/ins")).click();
 //have tried by multiple different ways to find this element nothing.
element(by.css('a.jstree-clicked')).click();
element(by.id('168283')).click();
```

Comment: You're going to need to edit your code posting cause it's missing parts of it.

Comment: @Rob html? Its very long. Someone recently discouraged I post anything but a few lines of code.

Comment: @Rob I added more code

Comment: No. I fixed the original problem cause you were missing angle brackets. Adding the rest of that may make your question worse by throwing in unnecessary elements and now you're missing angle brackets again.

Comment: You need to post enough code so that everything needed to debug is present, but not so little as people can't tell what is going on. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Leeish sorry i'm fresh out of university still getting the hang of things.  I went back and deleted the code I just added, if there needs to be more, please let me know.

Comment: I don't even know angular I was just pointing you to the stackoverflow info about writing a concise question to point out it's not always about providing less code, but the least amount of code required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably protractor is waiting for angular to settle down. Try clicking on element without waiting for angular like this -

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//li[@id='168283']/a/ins")).click();
```

Or wait until element is visible before clicking it. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it!!!!!  I wonder if there is a way to click it not using xpath... can you think of any?

Comment: You can use other element locator methods. Replace `by.xpath` with `by.css` methods etc..

Answer (score 1):

A small suggestion: have you tried to find your element with this?

```
element(by.linkText('Salon A')).click();
```